# Does Atlassian JIRA run well on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: software-installation, web-server, software-recommendation

Using the RaspPi to run an issue tracker such as Atlassian JIRA seems a natural use case. However, apart from [this Spanish-language blog post](http://mowaps.com/2013/02/17/instalar-java-en-tu-raspberry-pi-para-project-management/) nobody seems to have tried it yet, and that one does not give any details.

Is JIRA usable when run on the Raspberry Pi (i.e. are page load times acceptable etc.)? Any experience would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you think it would run fast enough on a 300MHz Pentium II? That's about the performance you'll get on a RPi. You can do a little better by overclocking it.

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but apart from the too slow CPU, there's also too little memory for all that Java stuff. I'm running a 1-user instance of JIRA on a Linux VM with one core and 1GB RAM: Takes ages to start and then performs just about acceptably.

Answer (score 7):

Information regarding system requirements for JIRA in a self hosted environment can be found at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+Requirements

> **JIRA Server Hardware Recommendation for Production**
>
> The hardware required to run JIRA in production depends on a number of different JIRA configurations (eg. projects, issues, custom fields, permissions, etc) as well as the maximum number of concurrent requests that the system will experience during peak hours. Here are some general guide lines:
>
> - For a small number of projects (10-20) with 1,000 to 5,000 issues in total and about 100-200 users, a recent server (multicore CPU) with 2 GB of available RAM and a reasonably fast hard drive (7200rpm or faster) should cater for your needs.
> - For a greater number of issues adding more memory will help. We have reports that having 2GB of RAM to JIRA is sufficient for instances with around 200,000 issues. If in doubt, allocate more memory than you think you need.
> - If your system will experience a large number of concurrent requests, running JIRA on a multicore CPU machine will increase the concurrency of processing the requests and therefore speed up the response time for your users.
> - For reference we have a server that has a 2 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5520 @ 2.27GHz (16 logical cores) with 32GB of RAM. This server runs Apache, various monitoring systems, and two JIRA instances:
>
>   - Our public JIRA site that has approximately: 145,000 issues, 255,000 comments, 120 custom fields, and 115 projects.
>   - Our support JIRA site that has approximately: 285,000 issues, 2,500,000 comments, 75 custom fields, and 22 projects.
>
> Please note that performance heavily depends on your dimensions and your usage pattern, much more than what is simply covered here.

Short answer: no.

Answer (score 6):

JIRA will run with a 6-8 second load time on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. This is probably too slow for most people and, as such, I was only loading JIRA to see if it could actually be done. Also, the times are on a fresh install.

I'm not sure what would happen when you started filling up the database, but I am definitely sure that it would slow to a painful crawl.